# can not generate selectonemenu items in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

hello i am new here in stackoverflow i am using primefaces 3.5 my question is that, is it necessary to set selectonemenu items(Map of java util) in static block or constructor..
like:

slider.xhtml

```
<h:outputLink value="circle">
<h:outputText value="click Circle!"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

pretty-config.xml

```
<url-mapping id="circle"> 
  <pattern value="/circle" /> 
  <view-id value="xhtmls/circle.xhtml" />
  <action>#{circleAction.action}</action>
 </url-mapping>
```

CircleAction.java

```
public class CircleAction {
private String favCoffee2;
private Map<String,Object> coffee2Value;

//setter n getter

public Map<String,Object> getFavCoffee2Value() {
return coffee2Value;
}

public String action(){
coffee2Value = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
coffee2Value.put("mohsin - Cream Latte", "Cream Latte"); //label, value
coffee2Value.put("mohsin - Extreme Mocha", "Extreme Mocha");
coffee2Value.put("mogsin - Buena Vista", "Buena Vista");

return "pretty:addcircle";
}           
}
```

circle.xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{circleAction.favCoffee2}">
<f:selectItems value="#{circleAction.favCoffee2Value}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

selectOneMenu is blank in this situation but when i remove below code from action method and place it in static block it the selectOneMenu will generate all items which are in java.util.map;

```
coffee2Value = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
coffee2Value.put("mohsin - Cream Latte", "Cream Latte"); //label, value
coffee2Value.put("mohsin - Extreme Mocha", "Extreme Mocha");
coffee2Value.put("mogsin - Buena Vista", "Buena Vista");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you access `/circle`, PrettyFaces will execute your action method and as you return `pretty:addcircle` redirect you to a new page. Because of this, all the values of your request scoped bean (especially the map) will be lost. Just return `null` from the method should work. In this cases PrettyFaces will just render the `xhtmls/circle.xhtml`, which is probably what you want.

Comment: then what should i do ? i ve<h:outputLink value="circle">
<h:outputText value="click Circle!"/>
</h:outputLink>

Comment: then what should i do ? i have <h:outputLink value="circle"> in which i want to call 'ACTION' method which process some data and rendered it to SELECTONEMENU as i did earlier after that i have a form where i select some value and submit '#{circleAction.edit} that value to same class (CIRCLE ACTION) but edit() method, but its not working because when i click <h:outputLink value="circle"> my browser URL is http://localhost/myApp/circle calling #{circleAction.ation} after calling URL is http://localhost/myApp/addcircle but selectOneMenu not wrking,

Comment: if i do with URL localhost/myApp/circle it always call action method but i want to call edit method too

Comment: should i use session scoped ? instead of request scoped

Comment: i want to call 2 methods in one MAPPING ID same action class (java file) is that possible ? one call by Link and other by button

Comment: Please don't mix JSF action methods and PrettyFaces page actions. JSF action methods are executed when the user clicks a button or a link. PrettyFaces page actions are executed each time a request to the mapped URL is received. These are two different concepts. And it also usually don't make sense to navigate from an PrettyFaces page action method.

Comment: then what should i do in this situation? i wanna use pretty faces, and wanna call two methods in same action class(java file) with different URL-MAPPINGID 1. /circle , 2./addcircle , when i call one method using /circle mappingID it works fine but when i call second method using /adcircle it works like loop....

Comment: 2nd condition, when i call one method using /circle mappingID works fine and i return "pretty:addcircle" as you said request will redirct to new page thats why java.util.map is not rendering , can't find any solution :(